# Why a cron is executed even if I remove the crontab line?

Tags: cron

I have a cron that checks if there are pending mails to be sent each minute:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/curl http://localhost/path/application.php >> /var/log/application.log
```

This script is working for years without problems. Yesterday I added a `echo` in the first line of the `application.php` file and got this log:

```
10:34:05 Launching application...
10:34:17 Launching application...
10:34:44 Launching application...
10:35:07 Launching application...
10:35:18 Launching application...
10:35:43 Launching application...
10:35:58 Launching application...
....
```

It is, the script is launched 3/4 times each minute.

My root crontab only contains the above line and the crontab of the unique user I'm using is empty. No other computer can access to my `localhost` server (I have double checked that it is isolated).

In order to check that the problem is the root cron I've commented the unique crontab line and, surprise! a similar log is generated.

So the question is: what's happening? is there any cron log or similar?

Comment: Look at /var/log/cron
Sometimes cron executions is logged there, if the file does not exist, check other important logs in /var/log

Comment: What operating system / Linux distribution you are running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm all but sure that what you need is

`/etc/init.d/cron reload`

Comment: Did this solution really help? It sounds really odd that reloading the cron-daemon would have such an effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look further, on many systems cron entries "hide" under the /etc/cron.d directory.

You'll need to check these out as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are few places where the cron entries can be listed. You may search for it by issuing:

```
grep "application.php" /var/spool/cron/crontabs/* /etc/crontab /etc/cron.*/*
```

This must be run with root privileges, so prefix it with `sudo` if you are in Ubuntu or similar.

The cron logging is controlled by the Syslog. (Unless you happen to have syslog-ng which has a bit different way to control things,) you may again `grep` where cron is logged.

```
grep -i 'cron' /etc/*syslog.*/* /etc/*syslog.*
```

`/var/log/cron.log`is the most obvious choice.

Hopefully this helps you forward.